# Cannot obtain cAdvisor container metrics on Windows Kubernetes nodes

Tags: windows, prometheus, cadvisor

I have configured a mixed node Kubernetes cluster.  Two worker nodes are Unbuntu Server 18.04.4 and two worker nodes are Windows Server 2019 Standard.  I have deployed several Docker containers as deployments/pods to each set of worker nodes (.NET Core apps on Ubuntu and legacy WCF apps on Windows).  Everything seems to work as advertised.

I am now at the point where I want to monitor the resources of the pod/containers.  I have deployed Prometheus, kube-state-metrics, metrics-server.  I have Prometheus **scraping** the nodes.  For container metrics, the kubelet/cAdvisor is returning everything I need from the Ubunutu nodes, such as "container_cpu_usage_seconds_total, container_cpu_cfs_throttled_seconds_total, etc".  But the kubelet/cAdvisor for the Windows nodes only give me some basic information:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/nodes/[WINDOWS_NODE]/proxy/metrics/cadvisor

# HELP cadvisor_version_info A metric with a constant '1' value labeled by kernel version, OS version, docker version, cadvisor version & cadvisor revision.
# TYPE cadvisor_version_info gauge
cadvisor_version_info{cadvisorRevision="",cadvisorVersion="",dockerVersion="",kernelVersion="10.0.17763.1012",osVersion="Windows Server 2019 Standard"} 1
# HELP container_scrape_error 1 if there was an error while getting container metrics, 0 otherwise
# TYPE container_scrape_error gauge
container_scrape_error 0
# HELP machine_cpu_cores Number of CPU cores on the machine.
# TYPE machine_cpu_cores gauge
machine_cpu_cores 2
# HELP machine_memory_bytes Amount of memory installed on the machine.
# TYPE machine_memory_bytes gauge
machine_memory_bytes 1.7179398144e+10
```

So while the cAdvisor on the Ubuntu nodes gives me everything I ever wanted about containers and more, the cAdvisor on the Windows nodes only gives me the above.

I have examined the Powershell scripts that install/configure kubelet on the Windows nodes, but don't see/understand how I might configure a switch or config file if there is a magical setting I am missing that would enable container metrics to be published when kubelet/cAdvisor is **scraped**.  Any suggestions?

Comment: fyi it's __scraping__ (and __scraper__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is metrics/resource/v1alpha1 endpoint. But it provides only 4 basic metrics. 
[Documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-node/kubelet-resource-metrics-endpoint.md)

I think that cAdvisor doesn't support windows nodes properly that you see is just a n emulated interface with limited metrics
[Github issue](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/2170)